# Facebook Checkbox plugin was hidden

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

I have try to add checkbox plugin but it was hidden. 
Please help me resolve that problem.

Thanks,

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '365440040557177',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.6'
    });  
    FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function (e) {
        console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
        console.log(e);
        if (e.event == 'rendered') {
            console.log("Plugin was rendered");
        } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
            var checkboxState = e.state;
            console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
        } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
            console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
        } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
            console.log("Plugin was hidden");
        }
    });};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the allow_login parameter is set to false, you will need to have a valid Facebook user session (i.e. not logged in as a page) otherwise the plugin will be hidden.